# Getting NoSuchKey error for an existing key on AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to use s3.copyObject() in my Node application to modify my file's content disposition metadata.  I’m using it to store the filename my user’s browser should name the file.  It's giving me a NoSuchKey error.  But, when I check my bucket's dashboard, I can see that they key does exist.  Furthermore, I was able to use the same key to upload, download and delete the file.  So, I know the key is correct.  I'm guessing that I am missing a parameter that is causing it to give me a bogus error message.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('../config.js');
...

static async updateFileInS3(strStoredFileName, strNewFileName){
    const updateFileS3 = async (storedFileName, newFileName) => {
        const bucketname = config.server.storageBucket;
        const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint(config.server.storageEndpoint);
        const s3 = new aws.S3({
            endpoint: spacesEndpoint
        });

        const strKey = config.server.storageFolder + "/" + storedFileName;

        const copyparams = {
            Bucket : bucketname,
            CopySource : bucketname + "/" + storedFileName, 
            Key : strKey,
            ContentDisposition : 'attachment; filename=' + newFileName,
            MetadataDirective : 'REPLACE'
        };

        await s3.copyObject(copyparams).promise();

    }

    try {
         let awsUpdateResults = await updateFileS3(strStoredFileName, strNewFileName);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(`[BucketUtil]Error updating project file for ${strStoredFileName}: ${err}`);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to modify the s3 object in place by copying it onto itself you need:

```
 const copyparams = {
            Bucket : bucketname,
            CopySource : bucketname + "/" + strKey, // The key should be the same.
            Key : strKey,
            ContentDisposition : 'attachment; filename=' + newFileName,
            MetadataDirective : 'REPLACE'
        };
```

Also note that if you are downloading via signed urls you can include the `ResponseContentDisposition` parameter to set the ContentDisposition dynamically instead of updating the metadata.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I just added the ResponseContentDisposition :'attachment; filename=' + fileName parameter to the call to s3.getSignedUrl().  I had no idea that was even a possible parameter.  I wish function overloads in JavaScript were as discoverable as they are in strongly-typed languages.